# Can Raspberry Pi 3 record 4k video stream?

Tags: streaming-video

I just want to record the 4k video stream from the camera NOT want to play it on Raspberry. Can raspberry pi do this using vlc ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official Raspberry Pi Camera does not support 4K, so No - If that is what you wanted.

If you have a USB 2.0 4K camera<sup>1</sup> that can dump encoded data then yes. As long as the driver is picked up you can use any software you like to capture the stream, even UV4L userspace driver.

I do not think USB 2.0 has enough bandwidth for RAW<sup>2</sup> capture but possibly if the camera encodes it for you with h.265<sup>3</sup> it should be fine. You just save the stream to your drive.

<sup>1 - Something like the PanaCast Panoramic 4K Resolution USB Camera - But Linux compatibility may be limited

2 - 4K at 24fps RAW - 4096 x 2304 x 24 x 12 / 8 / 1024 / 1024 = 324MB/s

3 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding</sup>

Comment: I'm not at all sure the pi has the chops for real time H265 encoding.

Comment: The camera encodes it.. not the Pi - So the stream over USB is already h265 and you can just save it to disk. Updated the answer.